# constant path for typeorm migration

Tags: migration, typeorm

iam trying to make typeorm migrations so how can i make this
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate"
take a path so when i run the command i writ
npm run migration:generate newMigration
instead of writing
npm run migration:generate db/migrations/newMigration

i tried some solutions like
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate .db/migrations/"
or
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate -d db/migrations/"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I need to write the command in this way:

```
"migration:generate": "npm run typeorm -- migration:generate db/migrations/$name"
```

and run it like this

```
npm run migration:generate --name=newMigration
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?